# Full Screen in Ubuntu

Tags: display, vga, ubuntu-14.04

I have connected my laptop to a Led Screen using a VGA cable. Everything works fine, the only problem is that it doesn't cover the whole screen leaving black patches at both the sides.(Horizontal)

I have tried using display setting but still the issue persists.

Comment: What to you mean by "black patches at both the corners"? There are four corners: which two are affected, and what shape are the patches?

Comment: I mean on horizontal corners there are black space shown @AFH

Comment: Sorry, you're still not clear: "horizontal corners" doesn't mean anything to me. If you use a different output resolution from the screen, then you will get vertical black bars at the sides of the display, or horizontal back bars at the top and bottom.

Comment: You could try this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

There you can set your resolution manually which could help.

Comment: by corners I did mean side @AFH

Comment: Will try that @CentrixDE

Comment: I had the same problem(just with a VM and one screen) and it helped me very much :) Good luck while trying it @AnuragSinha

Comment: If the problem is incompatible resolutions, then @CentrixDE's suggestion of using `xrandr` may solve it. But there are some things to check first. In particular, under `System Control` -> `Display`, make sure "Same image in all monitors" is not checked; see what display resolutions are available; and check whether you can change the monitor's own settings to match the best available output resolution. Also, if you could connect via HDMI instead of VGA, you will get a much better display quality, as well as a better range of output resolutions.